# image zoom jquery pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I need to zoom images  in side of the jquery pop-up

when the image pops up that image needs to be able to zoom 
I have prevent web kit zoom just the image needs to be zoom

here is my html code

```
<div data-demo-html="true">
    <a href="#popupParis" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade"><img class="popphoto" src="images/paris.jpg" alt="Paris, France" style="width:30%"></a>
    <a href="#popupSydney" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade"><img class="popphoto" src="images/sydney.jpg" alt="Sydney, Australia" style="width:30%"></a>
    <a href="#popupNYC" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade"><img class="popphoto" src="../../_assets/img/newyork.jpg" alt="New York, USA" style="width:30%"></a>

    <div data-role="popup" id="popupParis" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-corners="false">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img class="popphoto" src="images/paris.jpg" style="max-height:512px;" alt="Paris, France">
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupSydney" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-corners="false">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img class="popphoto" src="images/sydney.jpg" style="max-height:512px;" alt="Sydney, Australia">
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupNYC" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-corners="false">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img class="popphoto" src="../../_assets/img/newyork.jpg" style="max-height:512px;" alt="New York, USA">
    </div>
</div>
```

help please ...

Comment: Whats the problem with the current code ?

Comment: when I zoom whole app get zoom not only the image , I need to zoom only the image not the parent area

Comment: Ok, can you create a Jsfiddle for this . http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: actully I have done nothing to this only called default jquery js and css files

Comment: Ya i can understand, but without a practical example, its difficult to find a solution.